# Keep receiving phishing emails after reporting

Tags: office365, spam-prevention, microsoft-outlook-365, phishing

In my organisation we use Office 365 for email. When users receive phishing emails, we ask them to report them using the Report Spam/Phishing options in Outlook. However this doesn't seem to do anything other than delete the message for the user themselves.

Where can Office 365 administrators see and investigate these phishing reports? Can email alerts be set up? When a valid report is received we would like to bulk-delete the message for all users that received it, and train the spam filter to block similar messages in the future. At the moment even when users report every message they (and other users) still keep on receiving identical phishing emails from the same sender.

Searching on Google brings up results for "End-User Spam Notifications" and "Quarantine Notifications" but these are not what I'm looking for because they refer to situations where the server *has* quarantined the spam. In our situation, the phishing emails hit user inboxes and are reported by the users, but the reporting doesn't seem to prevent future spam from the same attackers.

Comment: As the reporting is part of Office365, it is likely that function "reports" the email to some kind of service; if setup for it: your IT department, but may also be: part of MS, or even a totally separate entity.

Answer (score 1):

The Quarantine page includes a comprehensive list of all quarantined email messages, including those classified as malicious, spam, or subject to other admin actions. This led to confusion. In the anti-malware policy, there is an option to quarantine messages that have malicious attachments, such as malware or phishing files. Additionally, the policy allows the configuration of common attachment filters to quarantine messages with specific file extensions.

So, a new filter called ‘Admin Action – File Type Block’ to the Quarantine reason filter is going to be introduced. By applying this filter, admins/SecOps can easily identify and review email messages that were specifically quarantined by the common attachment filter due to their file type.  This rollout will begin in early June 2023 and expected to be completed by late-August 2023.  To check more updates on quarantine management features like this, check out this blog.
https://blog.admindroid.com/quarantine-management-features-in-microsoft-defender-for-office-365/